# Custom named regex backreference in Python re.sub

Tags: python, regex, regexp-replace

I know that in Python regular expressions I can use named groups:

```py
import re

re.sub(r"(?P<name>test)", r"(found group: \g<name>)", "123test321")
# '123(found group: test)321'
```

How do I allow "custom" custom named groups? For example:

```py
custom = "some string"
re.sub(r"test", r"\g<custom>", "123test321", custom_group_magic={"custom": custom})
# should output '123some string321'
```

I can't see a way to edit the matched groups to include "custom" groups. Is there a way using Python's standard library?

Thank you.

Comment: `re.sub(r"test", custom, "123test321")` would give your desired results.  If you need something fancier, it would probably best be done by applying string formatting to the replacement string, rather than anything that the `re` module is doing.  (Groups are represented as starting/ending indexes into the original string, so it's not possible to have a group that doesn't literally appear in the string.)

Comment: @jasonharper thank you! Unfortunately, I'm getting these regex strings from users, and they are likely to contain a lot more complex things. I will look into formatting the string ahead of time though.

Comment: Your regex contains no capturing groups. Named backreferences are only used when there is a named capturing group in the pattern. What you ask for does not exist and won't exist. What you most likely are after is manipulating (changing) the matched text before replacement is done, and this is done with a callable as the replacement argument.